# Why doesn't Superman lose his powers at night?

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

I'm sure there are storylines in the comics and/or Smallville TV series where Clark's powers are grossly affected - sometimes weaker, sometimes stronger - due to events such as eclipses, sunspots, solar flares, etc. There's one Smallville episode where after being weakened (I can't remember how) sunlight coming through a window or crack in a wall falls on his skin and has an immediate effect.

If the light of the yellow sun has this effect, sometimes in a such a direct way, how does Clark retain his powers at night time or inside a room without windows?

Comment: I won't answer it as such as I can't provide any evidence. But from the Smallville lore I think that Clark almost uses the suns energy to recharge himself, so he can store the energy for a limited time. Also at night there is still energy coming from the sun. During the events my guess is that the sun actually releases different energy types so clark reacts differently.

Comment: In terms of physics, neutrinos from the sun don't get blocked by passing through matter so you get the same amount "hitting" you even after they travel through the whole planet. But it's a bit of a reach from light->neutrinos

Comment: I didn't think it was 'light' energy that powered him. Other wise he would still have powers under a red sun.

Comment: Not if it's yellow light  - a specific wavelength - that gives him his powers.

Comment: I really do think it is the battery situation, but I don't have any authoritative sources, so I'll let someone like DVK answer. :-P

Comment: The dupe has several examples of how/why Superman can use his powers outside the influence of the yellow sun.

Comment: Because Superman is OP.

Comment: We must keep in mind that the *Smallville* series took a LOT of liberties with the Superman mythos. Basically, Clark has powers outside of sunlight for the same reason we still have energy even after 40 days without food; our bodies store *way more energy* than most people would think, and it takes FAR LONGER to literally "starve" our bodies to death than merely going a few days/weeks without food. Clark's cells have been storing solar energy for literally years, so while he can deplete his immediate reserves, there is often a lot left. So he doesn't "need" *direct* sunlight to use his powers

Comment: Simple answer: **He's a living solar _battery_ which can condense and contain the power, and not bleed it out quickly.** Superman's solar storage and conversion is a passive ability, very similar to how _our_ skin creates vitamin D. Being in direct sunlight starts the process, but it doesn't just "Switch off" when we run into darkness. Beyond that, a human who doesn't eat for 3 days doesn't just "die" of starvation; his body grows weaker feeding of stored fat in his body. It's a long process that can take _weeks._ His solar storage capacity is similar in that he has _vast_ reserves at night.